# Dynamic equations for a gas discharge lamp

Tags: electromagnetism, fluid-dynamics, oscillators, non-linear-systems, shock-waves

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/299384/247642) asks why a gas discharge lamp is blinking and making a noise when it is turned on. I think that the lamp (with potential on) is a bi-stable system where the current-carrying "bright" state has larger basin of attraction than the dark state with no atoms ionized and no current flow (this might be actually unstable). With the potential off only the dark state exists and is globally stable. Once the potential is turned on, there is a bifurcation transition and the system moves from dark to light state - but small potential fluctuations might be enough to drive it back below the bifurcation threshold. It is only after the lamp heats a bit that the current-carrying state fully establishes itself and blinking ceases. (The noise is simply that of an initial electric discharge through the gas, as that of thunder.)

The questions are:

- The dynamical equations that describe the bifurcation (I vaguely recall seeing something in [Andronov, Vitt and Khaikin book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486655083).)
- The equations that describe the oscillations of the current when it is being established (i.e., the blinking.)
- The experimental evidence for this scenario
- The equations for a discharge front propagating in the gas when the switch is turned on.

Comment: Have you ruled out the current in the electrical parts of the system?

Comment: @honeste_vivere not clear what you mean by *electrical parts* and why they should be ruled out.

Comment: Sorry, just the usual $\mathbf{j} \times \mathbf{B}$ forces acting on electrical parts causing vibrations and noise.  Just thinking of the simplest possible thing first...

Comment: @honeste_vivere I think *Occam's razor* argument is not sufficient here: when we turn on the lamp we do have change of the regime from the one with no current to the steady-state current state, and there is definitely an ionization threshold for potential difference, below which the current wouldn't flow. There is nothing particularly *complex/difficult* about this. In your hypothesis, one should show that there are substantial (magneto)hydrodynamic flows.

Comment: Not necessarily anything solid (evidence-wise) on my end, just asking to make sure the simplest thing isn't hiding in plain sight.